# re.sub() exception for email addresses - python

Tags: python, regex

i have a question, with the following re.sub() method i am able to extract all mail addresses from a *.txt file.

`emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", file)`

Now, i'd like to remove all punctuation marks from this *.txt, because there is also some text in it.

I have removed the punctuation marks with

`output = re.sub(r'^\w\s', '', file)`

but this function also removes the punctuation marks from the email addresses in the text. How do i write an exception in this re.sub for the mail addresses?

Thank you.

Comment: one possible way is 1. reg replace all mails with hash strings(hash should avoid punctuation marks, and a dict to store hash and mail) 2. reg replace punctuation marks 3. string replace mails back.

Comment: I think you want `re.sub(r"([a-z0-9.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+)|[^\w\s]", r"\1", file)`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew thanks! Yes that's it. But does the r"\1" here the exception? Or how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r"([a-z0-9.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+)|[^\w\s]", r"\1", file)
```

Here, the email pattern is captured into Group 2 and the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern restores the email  text in the resulting string.

Note `[^\w\s]` matches any char other than a word and whitespace chars, and thus does not  match an underscore. If you want to remove underscores, too, add it as an alternative:

```py
re.sub(r"([a-z0-9.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+)|[^\w\s]|_", r"\1", file)
```